# Intent GridLayout to 4 Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I have `GridLayout` with a `CardView` inside. I want to create an Intent to 4 different activities.  I only can execute one Intent. I do not know if I should use `Else If` or `case`. Thanks for your help. Here is my code.

```
GridLayout mainGrid;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
    mainGrid = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
}

private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {

    for (int i=0;i<mainGrid.getChildCount();1++)
    {
        CardView cardView = (CardView)mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
        final int final1= i;
        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i=new      Intent(DashboardActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the line `for (int i=0;i<mainGrid.getChildCount();1++)` actual code or just a typo? Having `1++` instead of `i++` should make that for loop an infinite loop actually and might be the reason for your problem.

Comment: sorry i mean. i have 4 cardview and 4 activity. so if i cllick maps cardview will go to mapsactivity.and so on –

Comment: I know. Still your for-loop won't work if you have `1++` instead of `i++` in there.

Comment: already fix it. but still only tto 1 activity

Comment: That makes sense. You loop over all your cardViews and assign the same `OnClickListener` to them.

Comment: nah how to make for 1 cardview to 1 activity. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes from a lack of understanding how the order of execution of the program works. If you insert a cycle for and then you put inside an anonymous class as it is the case of `View.onViewClickListener` is normal that you will have only one result, because you break the for cycle.

The way to go should be to not use a for cycle, but assigning different Explicit Intents depending by what you want to obtain.

EDIT. On the base of your use case you need to trigger the Intent from the Adapter. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083837/card-view-click-on-card-move-to-new-activity) and mainly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick), basically you need to use the Android SDK functionality that tells you which card has been clicked `mRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view);` then depending from your needs  you may (or not)  pass a `switch case` for educational purposes, although possibly is not the most elegant and efficient way to solve.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: first of all define better your problem, why you need to launch the four activities  and run the 4 Intents?

Comment: sorry i mean. i have 4 cardview and 4 activity. so if i cllick maps cardview will go to mapsactivity.and so on

Comment: OK now is clear, you need to learn how to use the Adapter of RecyclerView please see my Edit

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different Activity to be started depending on what `CardView` is clicked try something like the following:

```
private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
    mainGrid.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    mainGrid.getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        //do this for all 4 cardViews.
}
```

In short: set all Intents separately.